# Display a table in an embed message using Discord PY

Tags: discord.py

I have 5 fields in an embed table.  The columns are really short as they only contain a 2 digit number so i was hoping they would compress onto one page to correct show a table of results. As you can see from the screenshot its putting the last 2 columns on a new line and only ever has 3 columns inline regardless of width.

Is there a setting within discord.Embed to set the width so it all fits into a table?

Here is the code for creating the table.  The lists are all joined using /n to format the rows.

```
embed=discord.Embed(
        title="Stats",
        color=discord.Color.green()
    )
    embed.add_field(name="Name", value=name, inline="true")
    embed.add_field(name="W", value=wins, inline="true")
    embed.add_field(name="D", value=draws, inline="true")
    embed.add_field(name="L", value=losses, inline="true")
    embed.add_field(name="T", value=total, inline="true")
    embed.set_footer(text="http://football.richardbignell.co.uk/stats")
    print("Posted Stats to discord!")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[image: Top of message]

[image: Bottom of message]

Comment: Pretty sure `inline="true"` does not exist. Have you tried `inline=True` instead? Also, embeds have a certain length and you can't drag them forever

Comment: Also I am fairly sure embeds can only display 3 columns side-by-side on desktop and only 1 on mobile

Comment: Thank you for the tips.  I have settled for a work around for now based on @moinierer3000 saying mobile only allows one column.  You are absolutely right and i overlooked that testing on the macbook.

Comment: @Dominik you are right. Thanks for the correction regarding the syntax although it didnt seem to make a difference either way as i can only have 3 columns in a row as moinierer3000 suggested.

Comment: Here is the work around i have used for now (not very elegant):

`rows = "\n".join(str(row) for row in game_stats)
embed.add_field(name="Date/TeamA/TeamB", value=rows, inline=True)`

Comment: Could you post your work around for this? I have not been able to solve this in a good way.

Comment: See the join code used here. https://github.com/bignellrp/footyapp/blob/main/cogs/commands.py